# ¿No se pueden poner índices al comparar un vector con un valor numérico en un bucle while?

Tags: javascript, while

¡Buenas tardes!

He creado este simple programa cuya función es decirme la suma de todos los números que introduzco por teclado hasta que ingrese el número 9999, si lo hago, me sacará del bucle y me imprimirá por pantalla el resultado de la suma anteriormente mencionada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica 9</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function inici() {
                var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");

                // Declaramos el vector "numeros" y demás variables.
                var numeros = [];
                var num = 0;
                var res = "";
                var i = 1;

                // Obtener datos introducidos por teclado.  
                while (numeros [i] != 9999) {
                    numeros.push (parseInt (prompt ("Introdueix el número: " + i)));
                    num = num + numeros[i];
                    i++;                    
                }
                resultat.innerHTML = "El tota és: " num ".<br />";
            }       

            window.onload = inici;

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

No sé si no sé hacer bucles en JS o algo, pero nunca me saca del bucle (aunque ponga 9999), ¿alguien puede decirme si yo me estoy equivocando o es que JavaScript no permite poner índices (i) a la hora de comparar valores en un while?

De antemano, muchas gracias y perdón si la pregunta es demasiado absurda pero llevo peleándome como hora y media y no hay manera.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que se pueden comparar números con los valores de un *array*.

El código para realizar lo que debe tiene 4 errores:

- Un array debe comenzar en 0 no en 1 (en la linea `var i = 1;`)
- Estas comparando el proximo valor (que aun no se ha ingresado) con 9999 en `numeros [i] != 9999`, cuando deberia ser el anterior (`i-1`).
- Olvidaste los operadores `+` para hacer la concatenación en `resultat.innerHTML = "El tota és: " num ".<br />"`.
- Al mostrarse la suma, se mostrará también el 9999, para resolverlo simplemente se lo puedes restar al resultado.

Con esas correcciones el código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
function inici() {
    var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");

    // Declaramos el vector "numeros" y demás variables.
    var numeros = [];
    var num = 0;
    var res = "";
    var i = 0;

    // Obtener datos introducidos por teclado.  
    while (numeros [i-1] != 9999) {
        numeros.push (parseInt (prompt ("Introdueix el número: " + i)));
        num = num + numeros[i];
        i++;
    }
    resultat.innerHTML = "El tota és: "+(num-9999)+".<br />";
}       

window.onload = inici;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica 9</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

y así ya funciona como esperas, saludos.

Comment: @Marcos pero estoy usando `i-1`

Comment: @Marcos si y `numeros[-1]` es `null`, por tanto `numeros[i-1]!=9999` sera verdadero en la primera iteración, de modo que si se ingresa 9999 como primer valor el bucle terminara y se mostrara la suma total 0.

Comment: Si, es verdad, disculpa. La lógica me pareció incorrecta.

Comment: Entiendo ... Muchas gracias, lo que pasa que, ¿qué valor tiene numeros [i -1] en la primera iteración? Si he puesto que i = 0, ¿tendrá valor -1?

Comment: @AlexIglesias de nada, aunque creo que para evitarte ese dilema puedes optar por la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Analizando el problema, la forma mas indicada de resolverlo no es con un while, sino con un do while, ya que necesitas comparar el primer valor ingresado.

Para eso debes asignarle 0 al primer valor del vector:

```
numeros[i] = 0;
```

y el código te queda así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica 9</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function inici() {
                var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");

                // Declaramos el vector "numeros" y demás variables.
                var numeros = [];
                var num = 0;
                var res = "";
                var i = 1;

                //el primer valor será 0
                numeros[i] = 0;
                
                // Obtener datos introducidos por teclado.  
                do{
                    numeros.push (parseInt (prompt ("Introduce el número: " + i)));
                    num = num + numeros[i];
                    i++;                    
                }while (numeros [i] != 9999);
                
                resultat.innerHTML = "El total és: "+num+ ".<br />";
            }       

            window.onload = inici;

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda!